# Django Middleware context handling issue related to variable domain

Tags: python, django, middleware

I face a weird variable domain issue when trying to define a middleware for django that will keep the request in the thread context. the first code section create an error when I try to access the method "get" from the API in the views file. the second code example works great. why???

Example 1 (does not work):

```
class ContextHandler(object):
    #_LOCALS = threading.local()

    def process_request(self, request):
        self._LOCALS = threading.local()
        self._LOCALS.x = "alon"
        return None
```

Example 2 (works):

```
class ContextHandler(object):
    _LOCALS = threading.local()

    def process_request(self, request):
        self._LOCALS.x = "alon"
        return None
```

common get method:

```
@classmethod
    def get(cls):
        return getattr(cls._LOCALS, 'x', None)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you have no class property `_LOCALS`, it is instance property. So in first case `ContextHandler._LOCALS` is `None` and `cls` in `get()` is `ContextHandler`.

If you want thread safe code don't stick with `@classmethod` and

```
class ContextHandler(object):
    _LOCALS = threading.local()
```

as far as I know class definition is processed only once (most likely in main thread). I'd rather initialize `_LOCALS` in `process_request()` and make `get()` instance method:

```
class ContextHandler(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        self._LOCALS = threading.local()
        self._LOCALS.x = "alon"
        return None

    def get(self):
        return getattr(self._LOCALS, 'x', None)
```

Comment: Hi, your suggestion does not work in Django. if you try to access the COntextRequest from the API (which is called afterwards) you wont get the _locals since it is defined for the instance and it will be a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that  declaring self.someproperty equals declaring .someproperty if the class has a class/static level variable.